# Optimize query load time for multiple left joins

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I need to improve the load time of this query

```
SELECT e.*, en.equipment_name as conventional_name, mm.name as make_new, 
mn.name as model_new, l.name as location_name, ht.shortcode as type_code, 
c.name as city_name, dt.name as district_name, d.name as division_name, 
z.name as zone_name, wo.problem_description, wo.created_at as complaint_date,
sr.action as team_lead_remarks, sr.submission_date as assessment_date, 
ccr.member_remarks as convener_remarks, ccr.updated_at as committee_date, 
wo.condemn_director_remarks as director_remarks, wo.updated_at as approval_date
FROM berc_equipment e
LEFT JOIN equipment_names en ON en.ID = e.conventional_name
LEFT JOIN makemodals mm ON e.make = mm.ID
LEFT JOIN makemodals mn ON e.model = mn.ID
LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.ID = e.city_id
LEFT JOIN hospital_type ht ON ht.ID = l.type_id
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.ID = l.city_id
LEFT JOIN districts dt ON dt.ID = c.district_id
LEFT JOIN divisions d ON d.ID = dt.division_id
LEFT JOIN zones z ON z.ID = d.zone_id
LEFT JOIN work_orders wo ON wo.id = e.non_functional_wo_id
LEFT JOIN service_report sr ON (sr.work_order_id = e.non_functional_wo_id AND sr.phase = wo.phase AND sr.is_team_lead="T")
LEFT JOIN condemn_committee_reports ccr ON (ccr.work_order_id = e.non_functional_wo_id AND ccr.phase = wo.phase AND ccr.is_convener="yes")
WHERE e.is_condemned = '1'
AND e.p_is_deleted = 'F'
ORDER BY e.ID DESC
```

This query returns arround 400 records but still it takes 15 seconds to load these records. Any help please

The last three joins are taking maximum time if I remove these last 3 joins results are returned instantly

Edits: Added EXPLAIN

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5R4f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add indexes to tables:

- **service_report** on **work_order_id** column
- **condemn_committee_reports** on **work_order_id** column
- **berc_equipment** on **non_functional_wo_id** column

If this will not help provide details

- How many columns are per this tables?
- Provide sql how you created this tables?
- More information can help a lot.